# The word "onto" - adjective?

Tags: terminology, article-writing

According to Oxford English dictionary, the word "onto" is preposition only but I see it used as an adjective in mathematical writings. I think it is grammatically correct to say that "$f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$", but in a very formal writing, is it considered as correct to write that "The map $f:X\to Y$ is onto"?

Comment: The universal language of math is "broken english" and not dictionary English :).

Comment: Thanks @voldemort! Any other examples which are considered correct in very formal mathematical writing but not in dictionary English?

Comment: This question is better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/ (where I'm also active, albeit less so). There are many examples in the technical vocabulary (apart from Mathematics) where "broken English" seems to be acceptable. But you don't even have to go that far. Consider "to" and "fro": these are both prepositions. Neither would be listed as a verb in most dictionaries. Yet the phrase "toing and froing" is commonly used and is accepted without comment by native English speakers. English is not exactly the most consistent of languages.

Comment: Mathematicians explicitly define words. Indeed, your "grammatically correct" usage is not very often used, because it doesn't work similarly with $1-1$.

Comment: English is actually quite forgiving with respect to the *ad hoc* formation of adjectives from phrases of any sort. For example, this sentence contains a not-quite-entirely-unexpected adjective. In many instances, such hyphenated adjectival phrases have eventually become adjectival words with no hyphens (that takes time, of course).

Comment: Am I the only one who'd prefer banning both "one-to-one" and "onto" and just using "injective" and "surjective"?  I guess I don't mind "onto" so much, but it seems to be inextricably linked to "one-to-one," which is sometimes used to indicate that something is injective and other times used to indicate that it's bijective!

Comment: you could use 'surjectively'

Comment: @Deepak: No natural language is consistent; that’s one of the few real linguistic universals. Present-Day English is, however, freer than many languages when it comes to changing the part of speech of a word.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I disagree: ‘$f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$’ is neither especially rare nor at all odd-sounding, and ‘$f$ maps $X$ one-to-one to $Y$’ is a close parallel.

Comment: I've frequently encountered *onto* as an adjective, particularly in books for students at lower levels. I would hesitate to call it "broken English" because it is clearly coming from the pens of native English-speakers who are otherwise good writers writing in a formal style. That being said, I was surprised the first time I saw it and have never liked it. If you dislike it, you can use "onto $Y$" or "surjective" instead. But it's common enough that it can't reasonably be described as a mistake, so if you like it, I think you should feel free to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recommend using "onto" as an adjective as in "The map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is onto".  I agree that this is conscripting a preposition into service as an adjective in an awkward way, and like many pedantic speakers of English it twangs unpleasantly in my ear a little bit every time I hear it for this reason.  In contrast, "$f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$" is *slightly* informal, but one can be slightly informal even in serious mathematical writing: I would not bat an eye at encountering it in a published paper.

It seems to me that the wide usage of "one-to-one" and "onto" in student writing is an artifact of the relatively recent (say, in the last 20 years) phenomenon of "transitions classes", i.e., intermediate-level undergraduate classes where students get introduced to logic and mathematical reasoning in an especially careful, deliberate, way.  In particular, the only books in which I see "The map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is onto" are textbooks for such courses.

(Well, to be honest, it's a little worse than that.  There is a recent genre of American undergraduate math textbooks which are, as far as I can see, not mathematically innovative in any way whatsoever and whose main pedagogical innovation is the adoption of a new, <s>less literate</s> more informal, friendly style designed to appeal to today's <s>less literate</s> busy students.  Thus I see sentences ending with the word "onto" occasionally in recent algebra, analysis or topology books designed for American undergraduates.  I trust you can tell how I feel about this.)

I really think that the expository reasoning here is no deeper than "We don't want to scare students with unfamiliar, difficult words like **injective**, **surjective** and **bijective** which are not as immediately transparent* as "one-to-one" and "onto".  That might scare them away from the concepts.  Let them learn the fancy words later."

I think that's pretty silly, in particular the idea that university students will find the learning and memorization of three new terms to be a significant hurdle.  (Remember biology class?)  Whenever I teach a course in which such terminology is introduced, I introduce both but make a point of using the latinate words instead.  In later courses I mention the latinate words almost exclusively, but will remind students of the synonyms when necessary.

*: Not as immediately transparent for an anglophone without a strong background in Latin or etymology, I mean.  I speak just enough French to appreciate that it goes over more easily there, and I am enough of a Francophile to like it a little more for that reason.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I used to prefer "onto" to "surjective" for no good reason, until I realised that the word "onto" may not be an adjective at all.